# Difference in REFERENCES statements

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

The question is simple.

Assuming that the following table has been created

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
( name varchar(20),
  address varchar (40),
  primary key (name));
```

I was wondering what is difference between writing a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
( name varchar(20),
  assembly_id numeric (9, 0),
  primary key (assembly_id),
  foreign key (name) references Customer);
```

and like this

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
( name varchar(20),
  assembly_id numeric (9, 0),
  primary key (assembly_id),
  foreign key (name) references Customer(name));
```

Comment: There is no difference,but the second one is more likely readable,because you explicitly mention the foreign key references

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
( name varchar(20),
  assembly_id numeric (9, 0),
  primary key (assembly_id),
  foreign key (name) references Customer);
```

Here foreign key references primary key of Customer table by default .

But in this code

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
( name varchar(20),
  assembly_id numeric (9, 0),
  primary key (assembly_id),
  foreign key (name) references Customer(name));
```

foreing key name references any specified Candidate key..As here name is specified.

So both does the same..But in first case since key is not specifed it refrences primary key.In 2nd case key is explicitly specified.

Comment: It is weird though, since every time I do the second case, SQL Developer requires me for the attribute to be a primary key, so in my mind, it goes back to being the same as the first one.

Could you perhaps give me an example where it shows how these two ways could define entirely different tables in SQL Developer?